# Using swash italics through fontspec

Tags: fonts, fontspec, minionpro, swash

I am trying to use Minion Pro’s swash italics in my files. The typical method, `\usepackage{Minion Pro}` and `\textsw{Text to be Swashed}`, fails when using `fontspec`. I need `fontspec` to switch between fonts mid-file; the document I’m typesetting uses several, most of which do not have direct LaTeX support, and are loaded as system fonts using XeTeX or LuaTeX.

Using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
\textsw{Qu’est que c’est?}

\emph{Qu’est que c’est?}

\textsw{Zygoma}

\emph{Zygoma}
\end{document}
```

properly produces

[image]

Note that the apostrophes are missing; I don’t know how to make LaTeX take UTF-8 (a problem notably absent with `fontspec`). This is impertinent, and should be ignored. More importantly, there is a significant difference between the swashed (first and third row) italics and non-swashed (second and fourth row) italics, prominently in the Q and Z characters.

Now, merely by loading `fontspec`, the Minion Pro package vanishes into the aether. `\textsw` does nothing and my text adopts the skeletal visage of Computer Modern. Using the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
\textsw{Qu’est que c’est?}

\emph{Qu’est que c’est?}

\textsw{Zygoma}

\emph{Zygoma}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Setting Minion Pro as the main text face works, but the `\textsw` command remains impotent, and I can’t swash my text; using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{Minion Pro}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
\textsw{Qu’est que c’est?}

\emph{Qu’est que c’est?}

\textsw{Zygoma}

\emph{Zygoma}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

Note that the `\textsw` command is provided by the Minion Pro package itself, and is not—to my knowledge—available as a generic LaTeX command.

How can I use Minion’s italic swashes with `fontspec`?

I may have had my PDF viewer at different zoom levels while taking the screenshots; please disregard any font size discrepancies.

I’ve used LuaTeX and XeTeX with this, and run into the same problem with each. pdfTeX works on the first example provided, but, as with Lua- and XeTeX, clobbers my apostrophes and doesn’t work with `fontspec`.

Comment: The package is without spaces `\usepackage{MinionPro}` and it works only for `pdflatex`  and the Type1 version of Minion Pro

Comment: With pdflatex you should also use `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` and perhaps `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\newfontface\Swash{MinionPro-It}[Contextuals=Swash]
\newcommand\textsw[1]{{\Swash#1}}
\begin{document}
\textsw{Qu’est que c’est?}

\emph{Qu’est que c’est?}

\textsw{Zygoma}

\emph{Zygoma}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, but perhaps it's better with `\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textsw}{\Swash}`.

Answer (score 2):

While user2478's answer works, I would like to add that the built-in way to activate contextual swash for \textsw is the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}[
SwashFont = * Italic,
SwashFeatures = { Contextuals = Swash }
]

\begin{document}
\textsw{Qu’est que c’est?}

\emph{Qu’est que c’est?}

\textsw{Zygoma}

\emph{Zygoma}
\end{document}
```

One should also note that this produces *contextual* swash, meaning in this case only initial capital letters not followed by more capital letters. It seems that Minion Pro lacks the *all swash* setting for some reason, which could be useful in words in only capital letters.